# Change Marketing Cloud Import associated to a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

**Background**: My team has created 16 different Imports in Marketing Cloud to pull in data from 16 different Sales Cloud reports. Each report is tied to a unique SF campaign. Let's call these items v1.

Because of new developments on the Sales Cloud side of things, the existing 16 v1  reports cannot be used going forward and a new report type was created. So, 16 new reports will have to be created in Sales Cloud. The v2 reports.

**Question:** Is there a way to connect the existing v1 data extensions in Marketing Cloud, the ones that were automatically created when the v1 Imports were created, to the new v2 Imports? I'm okay rebuilding the 16 reports, but would like to re-use the existing data extensions if possible. Especially considering each data extension is filtered into 8 sub-extensions, and all items are pulled into an automation.